# Google Sheets Index-Split functionality inside Arrayformula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

Given the string in Column A and the number in column B, I need to create a formula (Arrayformula) on Column C that will split Column A and bring in the n-th string. Column B determines the "n" (the n-th number).

Here is a sample Spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14plMNGpgKCsO-MQgQw1oFYsOVxIu3SWwllrDzpN0YFI/edit#gid=0

I know that this can be easily with Index-Split but I need the Arrayformula since it can sit at the header and not worry about the formula being written over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A10="",,VLOOKUP(ROW(A1:A10), 
 {ROW(A1:A10), SPLIT(A1:A10, "|")}, B1:B10+1, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. works great. Only had to add another IF to accommodate for the possibility of a 0 in column B (not hard)